# Expand column of Dataframes into existing dataframe (R)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe (4 obs x 3 variables) with a column that contains dataframes (10 obs x 3 variables each)
My goal is to expand each dataframe into 10 rows and 3 new columns but keeping the original matching.

The big dataframe looks like this:

```
Rows: 4
Columns: 3
$ ID            <chr> "A" "B" "C" ,"D"
$ report_type   <chr> "I", "P", "I", "P"
$ col_to_expand <list> [<tbl_df[10 x 3]>], [<tbl_df[10 x 3]>], [<tbl_df[10 x 3]>], ...
```

My first idea was

```
bind_rows(df$col_to_expand)
```

but that loses the ID and report type columns.

My goal is to end up with something like this that preserves information:

```
Rows: 40
Columns: 5
$ ID            <chr> "A" "A","A","A" ... 
$ report_type   <chr> "I", "I", "I", "I" 
$ newco1       <chr> "x", "y" ...
$ newco2       <chr> "z", "a" ...
$ newco3       <chr> "t", "u" ...
```

I ended up solving it by

```
new_df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 10), ] %>% bind_cols(df$col_to_expand)
```

but I was wondering if anyone had a cleaner way for a case where the number of rows in the column of dataframes is not consistent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::unnest` you could do:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  ID = LETTERS[1:4],
  report_type = rep(c("I", "P"), 2),
  col_to_expand = map(1:4, ~ tibble(
    x = sample(letters, 10), 
    y = sample(letters, 10), 
    z = sample(letters, 10)))
) 

df |> 
  unnest(col_to_expand)
#> # A tibble: 40 × 5
#>    ID    report_type x     y     z    
#>    <chr> <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 A     I           o     s     q    
#>  2 A     I           s     y     k    
#>  3 A     I           n     i     g    
#>  4 A     I           c     c     u    
#>  5 A     I           j     h     l    
#>  6 A     I           r     g     o    
#>  7 A     I           k     j     j    
#>  8 A     I           e     x     m    
#>  9 A     I           x     d     x    
#> 10 A     I           y     n     i    
#> # … with 30 more rows
```